# Derive the unit from the adjunction

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

In learning about adjoint functors $C \underset{R}{\overset{L}{\rightleftarrows}} D$, we learn about an isomorphism of bifunctors 
$$\text{Hom}_D(L(\cdotp), \cdotp) \simeq \text{Hom}_C(\cdotp, R(\cdotp)).$$

Suppose we call this isomorphism $\theta$, and suppose we want to derive from $\theta$ the unit and counit. The way my book does it is, given $X \in C$, take the map that takes $X$ to $\theta_{X,LX}(\text{Id}_{LX}) \in \text{Hom}_{C}(X, RLX)$. My book now claims that this morphism in $C$ is natural in $X$. I suppose they mean that for $f \in \text{Hom}_C(X,Y)$, the following diagram commutes:

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} X @>\theta_{X,LX}(\text{Id}_{LX})>> RLX \\ @VfVV  @VVRL(f)V\\ Y @>\theta_{Y,LY}(\text{Id}_{LY})>> RLY \end{CD}$$

How can I see that this commutes? Presumably it comes from the naturality of $\theta$ somehow...

Comment: CWM 2nd ed. page 80 gives a clear derivation of the naturality of $\theta$ (he calls it $\phi$) both in $C$ and in $D$. This is a more general result than the one you wish to obtain. I also edited a couple of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Roughly* Both compositions from $X$ to $RLY$ in the diagram agree with $\Theta_{X,LY}(L(f))$ as follows from the naturality of $\Theta$ in both variables.

*Some detail* For example, the naturality of $\Theta_{X,-} : \text{Hom}_{\mathcal D}(LX,-)\cong\text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(X,R(-))$ gives $R(Lf)\circ\Theta_{X,LX}(\text{id}_{LX})=\Theta_{X,LY}(Lf\circ\text{id}_{LX})=\Theta_{X,LY}(Lf)$; for this, note that the LHS is the image of $\Theta_{X,LX}(\text{id}_{LX})\in\text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(X,RLX)$ under the map $R(Lf)\circ -: \text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(X,RLX)\to\text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(X,RLY)$ induced by $Lf: LX\to LY$ through the functor $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(X,R(-))$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Trying to work this out...

Comment: @EricAuld: If you have problems, I can also give more details, but maybe it's more fun if you do the details for yourself.

Comment: Actually, I think I could use a few more details. Trying to put it all together. Certainly your answer makes sense, since $\theta_{X,LY}(L(f)) \in \text{Hom}_C(X,RLY)$, but I'm not sure how to exploit the naturality of $\theta$. Thanks

Comment: I added some details now, hopefully this makes things clearer.

Comment: Indeed it does, thank you!

Comment: I asked another related question, I don't know if you have some thoughts on that: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999797/unit-and-counit-are-close-to-being-inverses