# For natural transformation $\eta$ and functor $L$, is $(\eta \circ L)_X \equiv \eta_{L(X)}$ by definition?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors

Please see [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2409779/26327) for the source of my confusion.

Highly confused now.  I think I had to have gotten that answer right, because the pieces all fit into place and it's very close syntactically.

Comment: Yes! I don't know what it's worth, but you can take a look at [this text](http://www.iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/~Pierre-Yves.Gaillard/DIVERS/KS/).

Comment: $(\eta \circ L)_X \equiv \eta_{L(X)}$ is a special case of of  [horizontal composition](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/dept/conf/tacl2013/coursematerials/SelingerTACL20132.pdf) natural transformations.

Comment: I've never seen a notation that makes $(\eta\circ L)$ make any sense; there's not really such thing as composing a natural transformation with a functor. The alternative notation is instead usually $\eta L$. And for ordinary categories, yes, $\eta L_X$ is defined as $\eta_{L(X)}$.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard Thanks for that.   I will use it

Comment: @MaliceVidrine: The only reasonable notation for "whiskering" of a natural transformation with a functor is the same notation you use for composing functors. So if if you write composition of functors as $F \circ G$, then you should write "whiskering" as $\eta \circ G$ or $F \circ \eta$, and horizontal composition as $\eta \circ \mu$. Really you should consider all three of these as the same operation; but if that really gives you fits, in such arithmetic formulas you should always think of functors as being shorthand for their identity natural transformation.

Comment: (and, of course, if you write composition of functors as $FG$, then $\eta G$ is the right notation for whiskering, and $\eta \mu$ for horizontal composition)

Comment: @Hurkyl - I have to disagree with "only reasonable" since I've never seen anyone use $\circ$ for horizontal composition, and this seems to lead to little confusion. On the other hand, I would argue that most category theory readers will want to assume $\circ$ is going to be an associative operation, but $(\alpha\circ\eta)\circ F$ and $\alpha\circ(\eta\circ F)$ read to me as assigning $\alpha$ different domains if we want $\alpha$ to be composed vertically with something. Either way, notators gonna notate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to keep everything straight is to apply Occam's razor to eliminate all of the unnecessary entities.

Everything can be interpreted in the arithmetic of natural transformations, and there are only *two* operations: vertical composition and horizontal composition.

Objects of a category $\mathcal{C}$ are identified with functors $1 \to \mathcal{C}$. Morphisms are natural transformations between such things.

Arithmetically, functors behave identically to their identity natural transformation.

What you write as $\eta \circ L$ is (presumably) the horizontal composite of $\eta$ with $L$, sometimes called their "whiskering". Explicitly translating everything to natural transformations, it is the horizontal composite $\eta \circ 1_L$.

The "component of a natural transformation" $\eta_X$ is another instance of horizontal composition: it means $\eta \circ X$. Again, if you want a translation, let $\bar{X}$ be the functor corresponding to $X$. Then, $\eta_X$ is the morphism corresponding to $\eta \circ 1_{\bar{X}}$.

The values of a functor? Horizontal composition again: $L(X)$ means $L \circ X$, and $L(f)$ means $L \circ f$.

The equation you are asking about is nothing more than an instance of the fact that horizontal composition is associative:

$$  (\eta \circ L) \circ X = \eta \circ (L \circ X)$$

---

Note, incidentally, that for consistency, when you use $\eta \circ L$ for horizontal composition, you should also use $F \circ G$ for composition of functors, and you should use a different symbol entirely for composing morphisms and for vertical composition of natural transformations; e.g. $f \cdot g$ and $\eta \cdot \mu$.

I emphasize this because some sources use alternative notation convention where juxtaposition is used for horizontal composition and $\circ$ is reserved for vertical composition. In this notation convention, the equation you wrote would be written $(\eta L)_X = \eta_{L(X)}$.